# Protect a web site against hackers

Tags: security

I've suffering from hacker attack for one of my client website.
Each and ever time anonymous user adding unwanted code and hyperlink on my website home page(default.aspx).

Following code he added recently:

```
a href="http://www.ebk8.com/amdc/">symbolic code</a>

a href="http://www.ebk8.com/qxws/">symbolic code</a>

a href="http://www.ebk8.com/zqbf/">symbolic code</a>

a href="http://www.b2b110.com/bca/ ">symbolic code</a> 

a href="http://www.b2b110.com/bcb/ ">symbolic code</a>

a href="http://www.b2b110.com/bcc/ ">symbolic code</a>
```

symbolic code=different-different chinese or japanese language code.

These hyperlinks he or she added bottom of my default.aspx page with symbolic code as hyperlink text.Due to above code web page getting compilation error.Every day I am removing these unwanted code from the webpage on webserver.
My web site is running Medium trusted on shared hosting web server.
It has following permission for following user:
Permission attributes
--Full control
--Modified
--Read & Execute
--List Folder Content
--Read
--Write

Groups or User Names

*Administrators

--All permissions check

*System

--All permissions check

*FTP accounts (ftp_subaccounts)  [No permission for this user]

--Full control uncheck

--Modified uncheck

--Read & Execute uncheck

--List Folder Content uncheck

--Read uncheck

--Write uncheck

*Plesk IIS Anonymous Account (IUSR_sadgutn8)

--All permissions check

*Plesk IIS Worker Process Identity Account (IWPD_2677(sadgutn8))

--All permissions check

Plesk FTP subaccount (sadguru)

--Permission for "List Folder Contents" check

- Plesk Domain user (sadgutn8)

--All permissions check

Earlier it has permission for Everyone (full control) but I've removed that; also I've change all C panel and FTP account password.But still hacker continuously attack.
Can anyone please suggest me how can I prevent my website from these attacks.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to protect your site.

**1-** You should proper check your codes for open loops, like SQL connections or public js functions.

**2-** Use extra security checks for your URL, I suggest you to use [CloudFlare.com](http://www.cloudflare.com):

[image]

**A.** Cloudflare’s Basic Security Level is based on IP reputations and will challenge IPs that have shown problematic activity online recently. The Basic Security Level is a free feature offered to all customers, but it is not as robust as using the Web Application Firewall at stopping sophisticated attackers (the Basic Security Level only throws up a challenge/captcha page, which is largely only going to help with automated hacking attempts).

**B.** Cloudflare’s Web Application Firewall (WAF) will stop many hack attempts on your site. The Web Application Firewall (WAF) is a paid feature on Cloudflare, and site owners can adjust the WAF security level settings and rule sets in the WAF management console.